# Length of a string which is got from getline()

Tags: c++, string, getline

I have the following codes:

```
ifstream file(filename);
for(string word; getline(file, word);){
    if(word.size() == letters){
        cout << "word: " << word << endl;
        cout << "size: " << word.size() << endl;
        dict.push_back(word);
    }
}
```

In the codes, `filename` is a dictoinary file like "dict.txt". In the "dict.txt" is like this:

```
aa
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
...
```

As showed above, there are just many words in it. Assume that `letters` is 13. So I think the codes should print words that have 13 letters, like `abacterialope`. But actually it prints words that have 12 letters, while `word.size()` is 13.

So, why can this happen? As in my memory, `size()` should print the number of characters in a `string`.

Comment: Do the lines in your files have trailing spaces? Try printing a visible character to show where the string ends, i.e. `cout << "word: " << word << ">\n";`

Comment: Hidden characters like \r perhaps? What's your console output like?

Comment: On which system has this been executed? From where is the dictionary? How did it come to the system? - On output, print the string between '"' or similar.

Comment: @DiscoStu Yor are right, thanks! I checked the byte stream in the dict.txt, and found /r/n at end of line. Obviously this file is generated under windows and I run my program in a Unix environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all words are whitespace (space, tab, newline, carriage-return etc) delimited then you can get the whole file into the vector in a single function call:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(file),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(dict));
```

References:

- [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)
- [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

---

If you then want to remove all words that are not 13 characters, you can do

```
dict.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(dict), std::end(dict),
                          [](const std::string& s) { return s.length() != 13) });
```

References:

- [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)
- [Lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
getline(file, word. " ")
```

This will ignore any trailing spaces.